# Rounded Left Side CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to achieve the following effect with CSS, unfortunately my efforts have failed trying to modify code to get this even mildly right.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: can you share the HTML and CSS code ? and anything you have tried ?

Comment: have you tried using border-radius

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `border-radius`only on the two left corners and combine two values each, as in this example (you have to try around a bit to find a good combination):

```css
.outer {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  overflow: auto;
}
.outer img {
  float: right;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400/fb3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

This should be as simple as applying border-radius to one side of your image, playing with the values and image size to get the effect you require:

```css
img {border-radius: 250px 0px 0px 250px; }
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x500">
```

**More complex curves**

Additionally you can get involved with more complex curves like this:

```css
img {
  border-top-left-radius: 100px 200px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100px 200px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x300">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a curve on your image by using [border radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius):

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  padding-left:20px;
}

.container img {
   border-radius: 75% 0 0 75%;
   display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/800/sports/1/">
</div>
```